# how to remove "Modal state sequence" field from seqmsplot

Tags: r, traminer

Hi I would like to make a plot of the sequence of modal states (`seqmsplot` in TraMineR) but because I am making a figure which consists some other plots I would like to remove the in-build subtitle which says "Modal state sequence ..." because this is affecting the heights of y-axis. Does anyone know how I can remove this in seqmsplot and use main="Modal state sequence" instead?

Below is a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytEED.jpg) (from TraMineR website) which shows which part I would like to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Up to TraMineR v 2.2-2, the display of the info about the frequency of the sequence of modal states was hard coded.

The development version 2.3-3 ([available on R-Forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=743)), which will eventually become 2.2-3 on the CRAN, offers a new attribute `info` in the plot method `plot.stslist.modst` invoked by `seqmsplot`.

With this new version, you can suppress the info with `seqmsplot(..., info=FALSE)`. For example, using the `mvad` data:

```
data(mvad)
m.seq <- seqdef(mvad[,17:86], xtstep=3)
seqmsplot(m.seq, info=FALSE)
```

[image]